# Cannot run brew installed version of “laszip” on macOS

Tags: homebrew, macos-highsierra

I am running macOS High Sierra (10.13.2) and HomeBrew version 1.4.1.

I installed an app (`laszip`) on mac using `brew install laszip`. The app seems to have installed successfully. However, when I try to run the app from terminal, or find it using `which laszip`, it is not found.

Here are some details:

```
$ brew install laszip
Warning: laszip 3.1.1 is already installed
$ brew install --force laszip
Warning: laszip 3.1.1 is already installed
$ brew info laszip
laszip: stable 3.1.1 (bottled), HEAD
Lossless LiDAR compression
https://www.laszip.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1 (23 files, 551KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-12-25 at 11:41:22
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/laszip.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔
$ laszip
-bash: laszip: command not found
$ which laszip
$ where laszip
-bash: where: command not found
$ whereis laszip
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
$ brew uninstall laszip
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1... (23 files, 551KB)
$ brew install laszip
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/laszip-3.1.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/rcanand/Library/Caches/Homebrew/laszip-3.1.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring laszip-3.1.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1: 23 files, 551KB
$ which laszip
$ laszip
-bash: laszip: command not found
$
```

I also found that laszip is not under any of the binary paths:

```
$ find /usr -iname "laszip*"
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
/usr/local/include/laszip_api.h
/usr/local/include/laszip_api_version.h
/usr/local/include/laszip
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/laszip@2.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/laszip.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Aliases/laszip@3
/usr/local/var/homebrew/locks/laszip.formula.lock
/usr/local/var/homebrew/locks/laszip@3.formula.lock
/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/laszip
/usr/local/opt/laszip@3
/usr/local/opt/laszip
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1/.brew/laszip.rb
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1/include/laszip_api.h
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1/include/laszip_api_version.h
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1/include/laszip
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1/include/laszip/laszip_api.h
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1/include/laszip/laszip_api_version.h
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1/share/laszip
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1/share/laszip/example/laszippertest.cpp
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1/share/laszip/example/laszip.pc.in
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1/share/laszip/example/laszipdllexample.cpp
/usr/local/Cellar/laszip/3.1.1/share/laszip/example/laszip-config.in
```

How do I get brew to clean uninstall and reinstall so the app is available from command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [to this post on the LAStools Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lastools/7zzKK3678u0), all that is installed when you install `laszip` via `brew install laszip` are the LAS libraries.

To actually get a binary that uses LAS in place you need to install tools that then talk to those libraries like `liblas` like this:

```
brew install liblas
```

To be honest, I am not 100% familiar with this tool so you might know better than me what would need to be done with the command. But `brew install laszip` is not enough to do much it seems.

Comment: Thanks, this is getting me somewhere - yes, the link does require liblas - I already had liblas installed, but it was built without laszip, which is an optional dependency in the liblas formula. So, I uninstalled liblas and reinstalled `brew install liblas --with-laszip`. This gives errors that the file `/usr/local/include/laszip/laszip.hpp` was not found.

Comment: I landed up using the suggestion from the link, and built lastools from scratch, and that worked, with laszip. Thanks!